# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to send a post comprising text and an image to firebase database in react native.

The problem is that I am getting this error:
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyWsp.png)
In PostScreen the button to make the post is displayed. In Fire.js it is processed and also sent to the database.

I hope somebody can help me with that error.

PostScreen.js

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  View, 
  Text, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Alert, 
  FlatList, 
  ScrollView, 
  SafeAreaView, 
  TouchableOpacity, 
  Image, 
  TextInput, 
  Button, 
  PermissionsAndroid, 
  NativeModules
} from 'react-native';
import {Ionicons} from '@expo/vector-icons';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import * as Permissions from 'expo-permissions';
import Fire from '../src/Fire';
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-image-crop-picker';

const firebase = require("firebase");
require("firebase/firestore");

export default class PostScreen extends Component {
    
    state = {
        text: "",
        image: null,
    };

    handlePost = () => {
      Fire.shared
      .addPost({ text: this.state.text.trim(), localUri: this.state.image })
      .then(ref => {
        this.setState({ text: "", image: null });
        this.props.navigation.goBack();
      })
      .catch(error => {
        alert(error.message);
      });      
    };


    pickSingle = () => {
      ImagePicker.openPicker({
        width: 500,
        height: 500,
        cropping: true
      }).then(image => {
        console.log('received image', image);
        this.setState({
          image: {uri: image.path, width: image.width, height: image.height, mime: image.mime},
        });
      }).catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
        Alert.alert(e.message ? e.message : e);
      });
    }

    renderImage(image) {
      return <Image style={{width: 300, height: 300, resizeMode: 'contain'}} source={image} />
    }
  
    renderAsset(image) {
      return this.renderImage(image);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.requestCameraRollPermission();
    }

    getPhotoPermission = async () => {
        const { status } = await Permissions.getAsync(Permissions.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        if (status !== 'granted') {
          alert('We need access to your camera rool');
        }
      };

    requestCameraRollPermission = async () => {
        try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
          if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            return null;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (err) {
          return null;
        }
      };

    requestCameraPermission = async () => {
        try {
          const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
            PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA);
          if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED) {
            return null;
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        } catch (err) {
          return null;
        }
      };    

    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.header}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.goBack()}>
                        <Ionicons name="md-arrow-back" size={24} color="#D8D9D8"></Ionicons>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handlePost}>
                        <Text style={{ fontSize: 15 ,fontWeight: 'bold', color: '#1d6fa4' }}>Post</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

            <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
                <Image style={styles.avatar}></Image>
                <TextInput
                    autoFocus={true}
                    multiline={true}
                    numberOfLines={4}
                    style={{ flex: 1 }}
                    placeholder='Want to share something?'
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
                    value={this.state.text}
                ></TextInput>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.icons}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.photo}>
                    <Ionicons name="md-photos" size={32} color='#D8D9DB' onPress={this.pickSingle} ></Ionicons>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.camera}>
                    <Ionicons name="md-camera" size={32} color='#D8D9DB' ></Ionicons>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>

                <ScrollView style={{ marginHorizontal: 25, marginTop: 25, height: 150, }}>
                  {this.state.image ? this.renderAsset(this.state.image) : null}
                  {this.state.images ? this.state.images.map(i => <View key={i.uri} style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>{this.renderAsset(i)}</View>) : null}
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    header: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        paddingHorizontal: 32,
        paddingVertical: 12,
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        borderBottomColor: '#D8D9D8'
    },
    inputContainer: {
        margin: 32,
        flexDirection: "row",
        borderWidth: 0.5,
        borderColor: '#D8D9D8'
    },
    avatar: {
        width: 48,
        height: 48,
        borderRadius: 24,
        marginRight: 16
    },
    icons: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    },
    photo: {
      marginRight: 20
    },
    camera: {
      marginRight: 33
    },
    imgContainer: {
      marginVertical: 20
    },
    button: {
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      marginBottom: 10,
    },
    text: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
    title: {
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        fontSize: 22
    },
    safeArea: {
        marginTop: 20
    },
    dateContainer: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    imgView: {
        width: '50%',
        marginVertical: 10,

    }
});
```

**Fire.js**

```js
import firebase from 'firebase';


var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyB1Z4eYKBoQVxREriGRi9neur5pVbIr2d8",
    authDomain: "caring-1.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://caring-1.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "caring-1",
    storageBucket: "caring-1.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "369253724134",
    appId: "1:369253724134:web:49a7597841cdd55970f027"
  };

class Fire {
    constructor() {
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
    }

    addPost = async ({ text, localUri }) => {
        const remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(localUri);

        return new Promise((res, rej) => {
            this.firestore
                .collection("posts")
                .add({
                    text,
                    uid: this.uid,
                    timestamp: this.timestamp,
                    image: remoteUri
                })
                .then(ref => {
                    res(ref);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    rej(error);
                });
        });
    };

    uploadPhotoAsync = async uri => {
        const path = `photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}.jpg`;

        return new Promise(async(res, rej) => {    
            const response = await fetch(uri);
            const file = await response.blob();

            let upload = firebase
                .storage()
                .ref(path)
                .put(file);

            upload.on(
                "state_changed",
                snapshot => {},
                err => {
                    rej(err);
                },
                async () => {
                    const url = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
                    res(url);
                }
            );
        });
    };
    
    get firestore() {
        return firebase.firestore()
    }

    get uid() {
        return (firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid;
    }

    get timestamp() {
        return Date.now();
    }
}

Fire.shared = new Fire();
export default Fire;
```

Comment: do you have hot reload enabled on the device? if yes, try disable it. The device have an active internet connection, right?

Comment: @WiliamBrochensquejunior hot reload is enabled, how do i disable it? i am running the app on an emulator which has an active internet connection, because the authentication with firebase works.

Comment: try running ```adb shell input keyevent 82``` on a terminal, this will shake the device on the emulator, and open a window where you can disable it.
Or, if you're using AVD, you can go to the "..." button, and there you can shake your device using the sensors.
Will make the same effect.

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: anyone with a fix for this? @WiliamBrochensquejunior

Answer (score 0):

you must change in the function uploadPhotoAsync this
"stated_changed" to firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED.

```
const path = `photos/${this.uid}/${Date.now()}.jpg`;

return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
  const response = await fetch(uri);
  const file = await response.blob();

  let upload = firebase.storage().ref(path).put(file);

  upload.on(
    firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
    (snapshot) => {},
    (err) => {
      rej(err);
    },
    async () => {
      const url = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
      res(url);
    }
  );
});
```

thats work to me

Comment: still showing the same. My code is exactly the same as posted in the question, i changed as per your answer but it's still same issue @bruno